# How to load in image already zoomed out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, zooming

I am trying to display a large Image in my iPhone app. It behaves kind of strangely and I can't get it to center seeing as its so large. Is there a way to load it scaled down so that the whole image fits on the screen and then you can zoom in?

```
- (void)loadImageView1 {
    KFImageZoomView *image = [[KFImageZoomView alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"TrappsTrailMapImage.png"atLocation:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [self addSubview:image];
    [image release];
}
```

custom class:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KFImageZoomView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIImageView     *imageView;

#pragma mark Initialisation
- (id)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName atLocation:(CGPoint)location;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "KFImageZoomView.h"

@implementation KFImageZoomView

@synthesize imageView;

#pragma mark - Memory Management

- (void) dealloc {
    [self.imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - Initialisation

- (id)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName atLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Assign the delegate
        self.delegate = self;

        // Create our image view using the passed in image name
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

        // Update the ImageZoom frame to match the dimensions of passed in image
        self.frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 
                                self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);

        // Set a default minimum and maximum zoom scale
        self.minimumZoomScale = 0.01f;
        self.maximumZoomScale = 10.0f;

        // Add image view as a subview
        [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegates

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}


@end
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to load it scaled down, but without knowing what you're working with specifically, and what you've tried - we can't help much. Include some source code, maybe how you're displaying the image currently?

Comment: You are absolutely correct I will include code, but I am using a custom class to make my images zoomable would this be helpful as well?To start with here is the code I am using to display my image:            - (void)loadImageView1 {  
 KFImageZoomView *image = [[KFImageZoomView alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"TrappsTrailMapImage.png"atLocation:CGPointMake(0,0)];  
    [self addSubview:image];  
    [image release];                                                             }

Comment: Absolutely! If you are using a custom class, it's even more important to include the source code (at least anything related to loading and scaling the image)! We can't know the code/logic you're using to display the image otherwise.

Comment: yes you are correct I ave now added the class